# How to get node id in a block_view theme page?

Tags: views, 7, blocks

I have added blocks to my custom module. A same block should be displayed in two pages. I have to display the field
 $node->field_tag['und']['0']['value']; 
in my block.

```
$nid = explode("/", $_GET['q']);
$node = node_load($nid[1]);
```

I got the node id by this. When it goes to another url it is not loading.
So how can I get the nid in the block_view theme page without using the url?

Comment: You mean to say that, you have programmatically created a **NEW BLOCK**. And you are showing this BLOCK in 2 different pages. In one of the page you will get the NID and by using NID you will load a TAG field. But in another page your not able to get the NID to load TAG field?

Comment: yes @inizio that is my issue...

Comment: Can you able to pass **nid PARAMETER** in the **URL**?

Comment: No i'm getting the value of nid only from the url. so i cant pass it to the another page.....

Answer (score 2):

You want [menu_get_object()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_get_object/7) to obtain the node object when visiting a node page.

Comment: no it not works for me

Comment: menu_get_object() seems the recommended way to go. Why is it not working for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this (show a node's field in a block on only two pages) without a custom module. Make a block view showing this field. On the block configuration page make it display only on the two URLs that you want.

Comment: but I need the nid for loading some of the contents the block requires

Comment: Do you mean you need some content from the node you need to process rather than display the way the Views module can? Can you elaborate?

Comment: yes I have to load the node there in order to display some contents of the node in to the block. As now I'm getting it from url. it is not same as that of another page